# Oracle-to-SQL Server replication: manipulate data during replication

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g, database-replication, transactional-replication

I've "inherited" a working Oracle (10g) to SQL Server 2005 data replication using standard SQL Server snapshot and transactional replication.

Everything works fine - as long as Oracle doesn't try to send a date that's outside the SQL Server `DATETIME` range (1753/1/1 to 9999/12/31). I was hoping to be able to somehow get in the middle of the data replication, check for that date range, and if necessary, tweak the Oracle date being published to be something that SQL Server 2005's `DATETIME` datatype can handle.

Is there any reasonably easy way to do this?? I know I could just change the target datatype to VARCHAR(19) or something like that - and I know I could upgrade to SQL Server 2008 and use the `DATE` or `DATETIME2` datatypes to solve the issue - both options aren't viable right now (maybe in 6, 12 months or so).

Is there something I can do **right now**? And easily?? I cannot get too deep into Oracle to fix it here, unforutnately (that's another third-party company that doesn't like other folks fiddling around in their system).

Comment: I don't believe there's a solution to this - from what I understand, the replication process is similar to using the log reader for transactional replication, so it's not really running in an "SQL" context - it's at a lower, so a T-SQL solution wouldn't be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a solution to this - from what I understand, the replication process is similar to using the log reader for transactional replication, so it's a black box - it's unlikely that you could inject any code into the process, and if you could, it would be lower level code than SQL.